# I am getting always 307 temporary redirect for nginx ingress in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, azure-aks, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I am trying to setup a fast api rest api backend in azure kubernetes service and I am using nginx ingress. Here is my nginx ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dataxprt-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "100m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: socketio-service
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "1000000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: Content-Type, authorization
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "http://localhost:3000, http://localhost, http://xxx.xxx.com, https://localhost:3000, https://localhost, https://xxxui.xxx.com"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: xxx.xxx.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: fastapi-service
            port:
              number: 8000
      - path: /ws
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: socketio-service
            port:
              number: 8080
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - xxx.xxx.com
    secretName: tls-secret-prd
```

I have used a config map to disable hsts. The config map is

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  hsts: "false"
  hsts-max-age: "0"
  ssl-redirect: "false"
  hsts-include-subdomains: "false"
```

when I hit curl -s -D- https://xxx.xxx.com | grep -i Strict

It gives me a blank so I believe the above config map is working.
Here is my certificate and cluster issuer

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: tls-secret-prd
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretName: tls-secret-prd
  dnsNames:
  - xxx.xxx.com
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-production
    kind: ClusterIssuer
```

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-production
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: xxx@xxx.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-production
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```

Now the entire APIs are working when I am using client like Postman but when I am using it from REACT frontend using axios, only the GET APIs are giving me 307 Temporary Redirect thus it tries to redirect to a non http backend. Now I am getting mixed content error when hitting the APIs from a https REACT frontend. Not sure if I am missing any configuration.
Please help!

Comment: You may want to check once by making the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect annotation set to true. This will redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS even if the original request was not HTTPS. Also, kindy verify that the certificate and cluster issuer are correctly configured and the backend service is correctly configured to handle HTTPS requests